# Batch file for some reason adding a space in-between parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an odd situation where for some reason a statement in my batch file is given an additional space.

```
scan "%1" -d "db" --memory -r -i --max-filesize=100m > output.txt
```

When executed, instead of executing:

```
scan "C:\" -d "db" --memory -r -i --max-filesize=100m
```

it executes:

```
scan  "C:\" -d "db" --memory -r -i --max-filesize=100m
```

As you can see it adds a space in-between "scan" and "C:\"

Could anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: @Matt Because I get the following output: Warning \\?\C:" -d -db......

Comment: Getting the same issue with 
systeminfo|findstr /B "Host Name:"|findstr /C:"COMPNAME-SET"

Output:
Z:\>systeminfo | findstr /B "Host Name:"  | findstr /C:"COMPNAME-SET"
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're quoting `C:\`. It doesn't need quoting (since it doesn't contain spaces) and it looks like the application is interpreting the resulting `\"` as an escaped quote, resulting in an unterminated double-quoted string.

Welcome to the joy of batch scripting.